# Passing Javascript from .js file to head of HTML file and have it read as HTML code

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JavaScript file that finds out the cycle of the moon and then picks the two current moon images to put on my web page as background images.  I got it to work fine as images, but the design needs them to appear in CSS format as the "background-image".  When I move the code into the head (originally in the body) of the HTML file it just prints the code as text on the page.

The .js file says this:

```
n="body {background-image: url('../moon/n"+moonday+".png') no-repeat right top;}"
r="body {background-image: url('../moon/r"+moonday+".png') no-repeat right bottom;}"
```

The HTML file says this:

```
<script src="moon/moonCycle.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">document.write(n)</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">document.write(r)</script>
</head>
```

How do I get the HMTL file to read the print out (which is showing as this... http://www.dragonfly-design.net/2012/index.html )

Thank you for any help that you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do this is to have a stylesheet with one CSS declaration for each day:

```
body.moon1 {
     background-image: url('../moon/n1.png') no-repeat right top;
}
```

... etc....

Then in JS, just change the class on the BODY tag.

Put this at the bottom of the page to ensure the page has loaded before executing (there are better ways to do this, but this is a simple one):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.setAttribute("class","moon"+moonday);
</script>
```

One clean line of code that allows you to separate your styling from your HTML, allowing you to use an external stylesheet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it should, but nothing so far.  I got 29 body.moon CSS declarations in my external CSS file.  Should the document tag go in the .js file replacing the code I had?  Do I need anything in the html file?  Thanks!

Comment: You need your mooncycle code, which gives you the day/position. Then a script block containing the code I posted, plus a reference to your stylesheet. I'mm make a small edit to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, still struggling, stick with me if you can... .js file has this code after "moonday" variable is defined, document.body.setAttribute("class","moon"+moonday);     Then the HTML file has this just above the body closing tag... <script src="moon/moonCycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.setAttribute("class","moon"+moonday);
</script>  ?

Comment: Absolutely wonderful, that is it!  A bit wordy in the CSS file, but as long as it works I don't care.  Thank you SO much for the help, I was very frustrated, too many options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your css in a `<style type="text/css"> </style>` tag if it's going to be on page like that.

Comment: whoops!  Thanks, but still no images (however it did get rid of the source code text appearing on the top of the page!)